# Integrating differential solid angle over the unit hemisphere

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When reading about rendering topics I commonly run into integrals over a hemisphere similar to this one:

$\int_\Omega n \cdot l \, d\omega$

If I want to put that in *Mathematica* then I can re-parameterize everything in polar coordinates:

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cos\theta \sin\theta \, d\theta}\, d\phi}$

But it's difficult and error prone to switch back and forth while attempting to follow along with a paper or other source.

Is there a more direct way to solve the original integral?

Comment: Since version 10 Integrate can operate over regions (see the fourth syntax form in the [Integrate documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html)). Just define a hemisphere and integrate over it.

Comment: Unfortunately as far as I can tell with region integration you don't get access to things like surface normal vectors, so the utility is a bit limited.  Chad, can you include `n,l` that gets you that expression?

Comment: @george2079 Ah, sorry I wasn't clear on that. In my example`n` would be constant - the normal at some point on a surface. The hemisphere is over that point. And `l` the direction of incoming radiance, so a point on the unit hemisphere. Which I guess would also the normal on the hemisphere, actually.

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks! That seems to be what I need.

`Integrate[Dot[{0, 0, 1}, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z} \[Element] RegionIntersection[Sphere[], ImplicitRegion[z > 0, {x, y, z}]]]` and `Integrate[
 Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, Pi / 2}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}]` both give me pi. Can you submit your comment as an answer?

Comment: @chad There you go. I didn't use `RegionIntersection`, BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 10 Integrate can operate over regions (see the fourth syntax form in the [Integrate documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html)). Just define a hemisphere and integrate over it.

Example:

```
(
 ir = ImplicitRegion[z > 0 && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, y, z}]
) // DiscretizeRegion // RegionPlot3D
```

[image]

```
Integrate[{0, 0, 1} . {x, y, z}, {x, y, z} ∈ ir] 
Integrate[Cos[θ] Sin[θ], {θ, 0, Pi/2}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}]
(* π

π *)
```